# Execute unix Cat command in ruby language

Tags: ruby

In unix if I write the command cat pressing enter

```
hello
hello
hi
hi
```

<kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> will end the execution

I am trying to execute the same command in ruby language without unix commands as
vi poo1ruby.rb

```
STDOUT.flush
b = gets.chomp
puts b

$ ruby poo1ruby.rb


hi
hi
```

After that it is coming to unix prompt , It is taking 1 line as input, multiple lines is not accepting

can anyone try to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
while b = gets
  b = b.chomp   #or b.chomp!
  puts b
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `gets` returns `nil` on end of file and the `nil` object's boolean value is false, you can use:

```
while b = gets do puts b.chomp end
```